# Diagnosing cause of ERROR_SYNCHRONIZATION_REQUIRED returned by Win32 LogonUser API

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying use the Win32 LogonUser API to verify credentials of users in a C++ application.  I am constrained to use "plain" C++ as opposed to C++/CLI or similar, so I cannot use the .NET `PrincipalContext::ValidateCredentials()` method, for example.

Generally, the approach I am using is working fine, but when some users attempt to log in, I get the error `ERROR_SYNCHRONIZATION_REQUIRED` returned by the LogonUser call.

The code I am using is relatively simple.  I have stripped out the specific error handling code, but the main heart of the code is included below:

```
bool DoAuthentication(LPCWSTR login_id, LPCWSTR password, LPCWSTR domain)
  {
  HANDLE token;
  if (LogonUserW(login_id, domain, password,
                 LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                 &token))
    {
    CloseHandle(token); // = SUCCESS
    return true;
    }

  switch (result.extResultCode = GetLastError())
    {
    case ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED:
    case ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE:
      // Diagnose password expired
      return false;

    case ERROR_ACCOUNT_DISABLED:
    case ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXPIRED:
    case ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION:
    case ERROR_INVALID_LOGON_HOURS:
      // Diagnose user restricted
      return false;

    case ERROR_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT:
      // Diagnose user locked out
      return false;

    case ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE:
      // Diagnose bad credentials
      return false;

    default:
      // Diagnose unknown errors
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I have experimented with various ways of calling LogonUser, for example using different logon types and providers, other than `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` and `LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT`, as detailed in the [Microsoft documentation for LogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw).  No improvement was achieved.

I have also experimented with how to define the login id and domain.  There seem to be two allowed approached:

1. `login_id = L"myuser"` with `domain = L"my_domain"`
2. `login_id = L"my_user@my_domain.fqdn.net"` with `domain = NULL`

Both routes yielded identical results.

I cannot perceive any difference in the users in the domain, between the majority who can log in correctly and the few that can't.  There are no "special" (e.g. unicode) characters in the login ids or passwords, for example.  The users are in similar domain groups and have similar attributes.

Also, the problematic users can log into the Windows PC in question as a local desktop user.  They can also run the application themselves, but somewhat surprisingly, this doesn't resolve the error code!  Running the application as an elevated user also doesn't help.

The PC itself is a full domain member but is not a domain controller.

So, basically, the question is... has anyone else seen this error occurring, and/or does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve the error?

The error code `ERROR_SYNCHRONIZATION_REQUIRED` is described in the Microsoft documentation as:

> The SAM database on a Windows Server is significantly out of synchronization with the copy on the Domain Controller. A complete synchronization is required.

But I cannot see how to perform this action, programatically or manually, and Google-searching has not enlightened me so far.  As far as I can see, or our IT department can see, there isn't a synchronisation problem, but there seem to be no tools for this.

One thing we have identified, is that this error message doesn't occur if the user gets their password wrong.  So clearly the domain controller **is** validating the password and only gives this error **if** the user's credentials are otherwise correct.

A follow-up question would be, therefore, is it safe to map this error message to a successful login?  I'm very cautious to do this, but maybe someone out there has a good knowledge of how this error occurs and can give advice here.

Many thanks!

Comment: There is a group policy setting that controls how many and for how long cached credentials can be used when disconnected from the domain or the domain is not currently available.

Comment: Hi @RichardCritten, thanks for your feedback.  I think I found the group policy setting you mean, but there is also a setting that disables caching entirely (CachedLogonsCount) - which I have now set.  We are still seeing the same issue, though.  Most users are able to log in (so it is seemingly reaching the domain), but the problematic ones still can't.